# Concatenation of 2 strings and a new pointer returned

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I am not sure if I was dreaming or not because I can not find this function anywhere I look. The function calls for 2 strings to concat, then would return the pointer to a newly allocated memory block with the 2 strings fused.

Does anyone know of such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of anything like that in the C standard; POSIX C contains `strdup` which returns a newly allocated copy of the provided string, but that's not what you are asking.

Still, you can easily build it by yourself:

```
char * strcat_alloc(const char * first, const char * second)
{
    size_t s1=strlen(first), s2=strlen(second), stot=s1+s2+1;
    // Length overflow check (see @R.. comment)
    if(stot<s2+1)
        return NULL;
    char * ret = malloc(stot);
    if(ret==NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(ret,first);
    strcpy(ret+s1, second);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: A warped memory of strdup could simply be my problem.

Comment: If `first` and `second` point to overlapping memory, it's potentially possible that `s1+s2+1` overflows. And of course on bogus archs where `size_t` is smaller than `void *`. Might be wise to check. :)

Comment: @R..: it's a very improbable situation (you'd have to have a string bigger than half the address space), but in theory it's possible, and it's a check that costs almost nothing, so I added it; notice that `s2+1` cannot overflow, since the actual size of the array in `second` is `s2+1` (because of the `\0` at the end), and every object size in C is guaranteed to be representable by `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of [`GLib`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)'s [`g_strconcat()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strconcat) function?  It's not *quite* the same thing:  it takes a `NULL`-terminated list of strings, not simply two strings.

There isn't a standard function which concatenates strings into a newly allocated string in `libc`.

Comment: Yeah, this is seeming more and more like a dream.

Comment: I don't promise that there isn't such a function; GNU libc and FreeBSD libc each contain various nonstandard functions, for example, although I don't recall either having the exact function you're asking for. On the other hand, it's easily implemented as `#define strdupcat(a, b) g_strconcat(a, b, NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [Using strcat in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419604/using-strcat-in-c)

Also, [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html) provides a lot of functions to handle strings, if you can afford the extra dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf one, but how about this lightly tested implementation:

```
char* strdup_cat( char const* s1, char const* s2)
{
    size_t siz1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t siz2 = strlen(s2);

    char* result = (char*) malloc(siz1 + siz2 + 1);

    if (result) {
        memcpy( result, s1, siz1);
        memcpy( result + siz1, s2, siz2 + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you save the return value of `strlen(s1)` you can avoid the implicit `strlen` inside `strcat`.

Comment: @Matteo: OK.  FWIW now there's not even an implicit check for the end of the strings when the data is being copied.