# Unhandled exception for strlen in C

Tags: c, strlen

I have been stuck on this one for a while, I'm not an expert in C. Basically, I am trying to make a function that "safely" strcats a character to an existing char *.

I am trying to get the "dynamic allocation" method working from this example:

[Using strcat in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419604/using-strcat-in-c)

I have made a few modifications, I removed the var that's set by the realloc function (the compiler said that it returned void). I also modified it to only append one character instead of an array of characters. I figured this would change the "realloc" parameters, so instead of passing the length of the addition string, I just passed in "sizeof(char)" (x2 because the original had an extra sizeof char, i think because of the null terminator?)

```
char *buffer = NULL;

int mystrcat(char addition)
{
   realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer) + sizeof(char)*2);
   if (!buffer)
     return 0;
   strcat(buffer, addition);
   return 1;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
if(!safestrcat(str[i+j]))
    printf("Out of Memory");
```

For some reason, I am seeing this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x60f0d540 (msvcr100d.dll) in myProg.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

And the debugger shows me strlen.asm at line 81:

```
main_loop:
    mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx]     ; read 4 bytes
```

I'm sorry if this is a newb question, but what is happening? Why is the addition char not being appending to the buffer?

Sorry I should add, that it compiles succesfully.

Comment: Your call to `realloc` is completely broken - you need to check for success and then reassign the result of the function to your existing pointer.

Comment: Second parameter to [`strcat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcat.html) is `const char *` & not `char` as you are using

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 *by definition*. Using it here just obscures the code …

Comment: In case of using `gcc`: It is a good idea to use `-Wall` to enable 'all' warnings, which would have pointed you to the type mismatch in the call to `strcat()`.

Comment: String concatenation is **not idiomatic in C**. Doing things like this is going to make your code error-prone and negate many of the benefits of C. The only function you should ever use to construct a string in C is `snprintf`, and you should know the desired final size before you even allocate the string.

Comment: Thanks for your input @R.. I am basically trying to manually search each string for a particular symbol and then pulling out the strings in between each symbol, I thought that I would reconstruct the string, because I am not sure how long it will be. Unfortunately, the resulting string may be larger than the original, so I wasn't sure how to approach it by allocating a MAXSIZE for the string, does that make sense? Thanks for suggesting "snprintf" but I need the string to be in a character array, and I believe this function is just for printing a string right?

Comment: The first call of your function calls `strlen(buffer)` where `buffer` has been initialised to `NULL`.    That passes a null pointer to `strlen()`.   The standard specifies that `strlen()` has undefined behaviour is passed a null pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You forgot one argument
- `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition
- your `realloc` code is broken
- `strcat` doesn’t take a `char` as its second argument
- I’d just return the newly created string, like `strcat` does

```
char* mystrcat(char* buffer, char addition) {
    unsigned oldlen = strlen(buffer);
    buffer = realloc(buffer, oldlen + 2);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;

    buffer[oldlen + 0] = addition;
    buffer[oldlen + 1] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

**However**, pay attention to two things:

1. You *must* call `mystrcat` with a valid, initialised pointer – same as `strcat`!
2. In the case of failure, the function returns `NULL` – in that case, it’s the caller’s responsibility to ensure that the original buffer’s memory is freed. This means that you mustn’t call the function as

   ```
   buffer = mystrcat(buffer, 'x');
   ```

   – This may cause a memory leak.

So a correct usage would be:

```
char* something = "hello";
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(something) + 1);
strcpy(buffer, something);

char* new_buffer = mystrcat(buffer, 'x');
if (new_buffer == NULL) {
    free(buffer);
    exit(1);
}

buffer = new_buffer;
```

Yes, convoluted. This is the price for safe memory operations.

Comment: If realloc fails then you leak memory.

Comment: It is better to use another pointer for return value of `realloc` otherwise you end up leaking memory if `realloc` fails

Comment: @another.anon.coward I disagree. The *client* still has the pointer and should be responsible for freeing the memory. This function usually shouldn’t be responsible to free client-allocated memory, no? Of course, this is a matter of (documented) convention but I’d prefer to separate these concerns.

Comment: @Konrad: `buffer` is a global in the OP's code (I know, I know...), so in this case it really is a memory leak.

Comment: @PaulR Yes but I changed the signature.

Comment: I agree with you about the responsibility of client to manage the memory allocated, client will have to be careful not to call the function as `buffer = mystrcat(buffer, ...);`

Comment: @Konrad: sorry - I missed that.

Comment: On this line: `buffer = realloc(buffer, oldlen + 2);` I am getting this error: `'=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'`

Comment: @Pete Use a C compiler, not a C++ compiler …!

Comment: ah ok, i am using vs2010, oops! ty

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Your code (and OP's code) invokes `strlen(NULL)` the  first time it is called. This is the cause of OP's segfault. Try `unsigned oldlen = buffer? strlen(buffer) : 0;`

Comment: @Robᵩ To be honest, I didn’t even look at OP’s usage, I’d assumed that it was used analogously to `strcat` … I’ll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to realloc is completely broken - you need to check for success and then reassign the result of the function to your existing pointer.

You also need a `char *` to pass as the second parameter to `strcat`, not a `char`.

Change:

```
int mystrcat(char addition)
{
   realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer) + sizeof(char)*2);
   if (!buffer)
     return 0;
   strcat(buffer, addition);
   return 1;
}
```

to:

```
int mystrcat(char addition)
{
   char st[2] = { addition, '\0' };               // make temporary string to hold `addition`
   int len = buffer != NULL ? strlen(buffer) : 0; // NB: handle case where `buffer` has not yet been allocated
   char * tmp = realloc(buffer, len + 2);         // increase size of `buffer`
   if (!tmp)                                      // handle realloc failure
     return 0;
   buffer = tmp;
   strcat(buffer, st);                            // append `addition`
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Explanation for OP: 1) `st[2]` handles the additional char + null terminator and can be passed as is to `strcat`. 2) Use a tmp buffer so that you do not modify the original string if `reallocation` fails and to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: The call to `strcat()` is still mssing the `&` operator for the second parameter.

Comment: @alk: `st` is `char [2]` which will decay to `char*`, there is no need for &

Comment: @alk: nope - I'm passing a temporary `char *`, `st`, as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks Joe, @Paul would it be acceptable to cast addition as (char *) or would this lose its value?

Comment: Oops, this somehow changed (got corrected) while I wrote the comment. Good.

Comment: @Pete: no - you need a 0-terminated `char *` for `strcat` - a single `char` won't do.

Answer (score 2):

Loads of really good advice has been given in the other answers, but the reason that you are getting the access violation is because `buffer` starts out as `NULL`.  Then you do `strlen(buffer)`.  `strlen()` works by counting the characters starting from the address passed in until it gets to a `'\0'`.  So in your case, the first time in, you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Great point, this wasn't really made clear in the other answers (even though they gave me some great advice and code to fix the problem)

Answer (score 1):

```
char * mystrcat(char *str, char addition)
{
   size_t len;
   len = strlen(str);
   str = realloc(str, len + 2);
   if (!str)
     return NULL; /* ... */
   str[len++] = addition;
   str[len] = 0;
   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *mystrcat(char *buffer, char addition) {
    char *bb;
    size_t ll;
    ll = buffer ? strlen(buffer) : 0;
    bb = realloc(buffer, ll + 2);
    if(!bb){
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory exhausted in function: mystrcat !\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer = bb; // Safe!!!
    buffer[ll] = addition;
    buffer[ll+1] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Something like that. So if no memory most likely you can't do anything at all until finish your application. If only your system not be shutdown.

It's a critical error! But you can see this message. In logs surely. No guaranties to work correctly if you pass bad prt buffer. For example if your forgot to set null terminator. Error occurs at strlen!